# How to loop this particular json object array

Tags: html, arrays, json

I have created a JSON object which I want to display in a div: question and number of selections-format.

How to loop i.e. iterate this particular JSON object array in div?

```
[
    {
        "question": "php Developer ?",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "mandatory": "yes",
        "answer": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
        ],
        "answerss": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
    },
    {
        "question": "1+1",
        "type": "radio",
        "mandatory": "no",
        "answer": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ],
        "answerss": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
]
```

**like**

```
Question
answer 1
answer 2
answer 3
answer 4
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please see also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use javascript . You are using angular js ? 
if not ..
Visit this link probably help you [How do I dynamically populate html elements with JSON Data with Javascript not jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314712/how-do-i-dynamically-populate-html-elements-with-json-data-with-javascript-not-j)

Answer (score 0):

### Angular Js

You can achieve this using ng-repeat directive like -

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <div class="preview">Question - {{question.question}} </div>
         <div ng-repeat="answer in question.answerss">
           {{answer}}
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Working jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/z800015w/

## Jquery

With Jquery you need to update innerHTML of the div by using following code -

```
$.each(questions, function(index, question){
    var newItem = "<div> Q - "+ question.question + "<div></br>Answer - </br>";
    $.each(question.answerss, function(index2, answer){
    newItem = newItem + answer+"</br>";
    });
    inHTML = inHTML + newItem+"</br>";  
});
```

Please find demo - https://jsfiddle.net/umd7nnhu/2/

Comment: is it not possible with jquery. because for angular js to work , i will be required to include one more angularjs library .and it will increase loading time .