# How to get JS data to HTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get my JSON data ptinted to HTML. So I used the JSON data and made it variable.Then I assigned more variables to access the data of each element I want inside JSON data. Now, I have my data in form of variables but I couldn't pass it to HTML by using document.getElementById. It might be because as I have different data for same variable, only the last element is printing out for Id as it is unique.  So,please help me on how I can print the JS variable data to HTML .

```js
var obj = [{
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hey there",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "welcome",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Help me",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  }
];

for (var i in obj) {
  var type = obj[i].type;

  var text = obj[i].text;

  var source_team = obj[i].source_team;

  var user_profile = obj[i].user_profile;

  var real_name = user_profile.real_name;


  console.log(source_team + " : " + real_name);

  console.log(text);

  document.getElementsByClassName('a1').innerHTML = text;

}
```

```html
<h2>Convert a string written in JSON format, into a JavaScript object.</h2>

<p id="output"></p>
<p class="a1"></p>
```

Comment: Try changing `var i in obj` to `let i in obj`

Comment: No,it doesn't help.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('a1')` returns an "array like" object. So trying to change the `innerHTML` property of that object won't work. Just to be clear. Do you want to generate new elements dynamically based on what is inside your JSON, or do you want to modify the existing elements?

Comment: Your using getElement(s)ByClassName then your trying to set an array.innerHTML to the text, you need to use getElement not getElement(s)

Comment: `let i of obj` iterates through the properties of an object, `i` being the property.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier. I just want the JSON data to be printed to HTML regardless of any possible way.please help me how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically populate html elements with JSON Data with Javascript not jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314712/how-do-i-dynamically-populate-html-elements-with-json-data-with-javascript-not-j)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to put this into a simple table. Generally, you can use the `.innerHTML` or `.innerText` properties to dyanmically add items to your HTML:

```js
var obj = [{
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "hey there",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "welcome",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  },
  {
    "client_msg_id": "3a223f8d-b5aa-4c9c-9b63-045ec6f90b58",
    "type": "message",
    "text": "Help me",
    "source_team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "team": "TN4AF0V5W",
    "user_profile": {
      "real_name": "marvelmohinish99",
      "team": "TN4AF0V5W"
    }
  }
];

for (var i in obj) {
  var type = obj[i].type;

  var text = obj[i].text;

  var source_team = obj[i].source_team;

  var user_profile = obj[i].user_profile;

  var real_name = user_profile.real_name;

 var message = document.createElement("tr");
  message.innerHTML =
   "<td>" + type +
    "</td><td>" + text +
    "</td><td>" + source_team +
    "</td><td>" + user_profile +
  "</td><td>" + real_name + "</td>";

  document.getElementsByClassName('a1')[0].append(message);

}
```

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
<table class="a1">
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Text</th>
  <th>Source Team</th>
  <th>User Profile</th>
  <th>Real Name</th>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we like print it linearly like one below the other without box?

Comment: I mean can we do it by taking off table styling?

Comment: Sure, you'd just change the way the HTML is structured. So instead of the `table` and `td` elements, use `div`s or something like that.

Comment: I ran into problem again.

Comment: for (var i in obj) {
  var type = obj[i].type;

  var text = obj[i].text;

  var source_team = obj[i].source_team;

  var user_profile = obj[i].user_profile;

  var real_name = user_profile.real_name;

  var message = document.createElement("tr");
  message.innerHTML =
     + type +
     + text + source_team +
     + user_profile +
     + real_name;

  document.getElementsByClassName('a1')[0].append(message);

}

Comment: NaNTN4AF0V5WNaNNaN
NaNTN4AF0V5WNaNNaN
NaNTN4AF0V5WNaNNaN